# ViewPager2 есть ли метод для перехода на следующий слайд?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Я изучаю ViewPager2 по этой [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2) и мне нелогичен один момент. Вот часть кода из класса ScreenSlidePagerActivity ([вот ссылка на эту часть](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2#viewpager)):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}
```

Мне кажется что этот код делает так, чтобы при слайде назад показывался прошлый фрагмент, но вот вопрос: почему тогда нету такого же метода `onForwardPressed()` или что-то типа того, и существует ли такой метод вообще? Я искал в документациях, но так и не нашел. Просто подобный метод мне нужен для реализации программы.

Comment: OnBackPressed() это переопределенный коллбек в Activity срабатывающий при нажатии кнопки назад. Так как кнопки вперёд у нас в Андроиде нет, такой метод не нужен. У самого viewpager есть только метод setCurrentItem() с указанием позиции элемента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас же все в комментариях написано...

> Мне кажется что этот код делает так, чтобы при слайде назад показывался прошлый фрагмент

Вам кажется. Это легко гуглится. `onBackPressed` - вызывается когда нажата кнопка назад. В вашем случае проверяется индекс текущего элемента. Если первый(нулевой), то вызывается обработчик по умолчанию(это закрытие активити или приложения). Если не первый, то показываете предыдущий слайдер.

> почему тогда нету такого же метода onForwardPressed() или что-то типа того, и существует ли такой метод вообще?

Кнопки вперед в android еще не придумали